# Python Remote Command line

Tags: python, telnet

How do i setup a local server such that whenever someone telnets in to the server at the specified port number , a python command line must be displayed at the specified location on the remote machine so that i can remotely run my python modules.
I'm new to Python. So Please enlighten me whether this is possible. If so How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more a question about how to invoke a program when someone connects to a telnet server.  The program could be written in any language (including, but not restricted to python).  The answer depends on the operating system of the remote server.  You also have to differentiate if you want to have this behavior for all users that log in, or only to some users.

Comment: I'm currently using a Windows Server. And i just want to test it out remotely.Thus there is no restriction on the users as such. Would appreciate it if you could guide me.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know the answer in a different operating system (linux).  However, for implementing a telnet server on Windows, you will have to use some kind of external program (see other answers).  There may be an option like "program to run on login" or "shell to execute on login" for whatever program you use, or something close to it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[WMI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/WMI/) might be the answer you want. And [Here](http://timgolden.me.uk/python/wmi/tutorial.html) is a good tutorial.